# Transforming an array of equations as a canonical form?

Tags: linear-programming

Today was my first course of linear programing,
I've just read again my notes and I'm not sure how does this array of equations actually transformed itself.

\begin{equation*}
       \begin{cases}
        \max a^Tx+b^Ty+c^Tz \\ \\
        Ax + By+ Cz \le d\\
        Dx + Ey + Fz \ge e\\
        Gx + Hy + Iz =f\\ \\
        a\ge0,b\le 0
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Is it transformed as a canonical form as

\begin{equation*}
       \begin{cases}
        \max a^Tx-b^Ty+c^Tz \\ \\
        Ax - By+ Cz \le d\\
        -Dx + Ey - Fz \le -e\\ \\
        Gx - Hy + Iz \le f\\ 
        -Gx + hy -Iz \le -f\\ \\
        a\ge0,b\le 0
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Just make a change of variable: $y \to -y.$

Comment: and $f$ was splited in two cases, isn't it? But what about $z$, does anything sould have be done as far as there is no constraints on him?